# Dark theme not applied correctly, statusbar color unchanged

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

I am trying to create a **light** and **dark** theme for my application.
When applying the light theme the statusbar is orange as it should be but as soon as I *switch to the dark theme* the **statusbar** stays orange although **I want it to be black.**

I am not a pro in theming so any help is really appreciated.

I included some screenshots, so you can see what I mean.

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

**I found a solution myself** (should somebody else have the same problem), in the beginning of my Loginactivity I check which theme is applied through a SharedPrefs file.

```
// which theme is set.
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Helper.PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Helper.newTheme = settings.getInt("themeCustom", 0);
```

If the black theme is set, then I just modify the statusbar myself with the WindowManager:

```
if (Helper.newTheme == Helper.THEME_DARK) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#1B1C1C"));
            }

            this.setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme);
     ===
}
```

Case closed..

[image: Light Theme]

[image: Dark Theme]

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- reference to CardView White/Dark styles -->
    <attr name="cardStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="txtBgStyle" format="reference" />

    <!-- Light application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FD8300</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#F59F00</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <!-- v7.widget.CardView background color -->
        <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
        <item name="txtBgStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Dark application theme. -->
    <style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FD8300</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B1C1C</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">#FAFAFA</item>
        <!-- v7.widget.CardView background color -->
        <item name="cardStyle">@style/cardStyle</item>
        <item name="txtBgStyle">@style/txtBgStyle</item>
    </style>

    <!-- v7.widget.CardView dark style -->
    <style name="cardStyle">
        <!-- Card background color -->
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">#282929</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Custom dark style for textviews, layouts, etc -->
    <style name="txtBgStyle">
        <item name="android:background">#282929</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />  
</resources>
```

Styles v21:

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapp.example.com.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:noHistory="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you have to override the themes in styles.xml, and change the toolbar color in that.

Comment: @NarendraBaratam I got no clue how to. Could you pls give an example for my code?

Answer (score 0):

go to your style

add this codes in your theme in style

```
    <item name="colorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
```

Comment: Hi, that also changes the toolbar to black, it should stay orange when the light theme is applied. I only want the "statusbar" to be black also when applying the "dark theme", toolbar should stay orange in light and dark theme.
Pls have a look at my style.xml

Comment: oo that case go to your layout xml file and and add this code android:background="#000000"

Comment: I updated my screenshot for the dark theme, so you know what I mean.
Would be great if you can help, maybe it`s also something in the AndroidManifest.xml what I posted? Don`t know.

Comment: see i gave you another answer for that..all you have to do that just open your actvity xml file and add this 1line code on top layout thats it

Comment: did you get that ? or else send me your mainactvity xml file i ll tell you.

Answer (score 0):

in your parent layout 
  add this code

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"//this is the main code use this line in your code
    ></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thx but this is not how it should work. It should be like, when I apply my light theme, statusbar should be orange, wgen I apply my dark theme statusbar should be black.

Answer (score 0):

set colorPrimaryDark properly in styles.xml of values-v21 like below -

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.YourTheme">

        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryBackgroundDark</item>

    </style>
```

To change status bar color you have to change - colorPrimaryDark

for app bar you have to change - colorPrimary

Answer (score 0):

just edit this
`<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>`

Theme.AppCompat causes "colorPrimaryDark" to be your status bar color by default.
Just change that to any value.

"colorPrimary" value changes your toolbar color

hope that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

This code will change the themes as you want.You should make both `colorprimary`and `colorprimaryDark` override and edit in your styles.xml file.

***Update***

The Problem is with your parent theme in LightTheme, the parent should be `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

**LightTheme** : colorprimary=orange, colorprimaryDark=DarkOrange.

**DarkTheme**  : colorprimary=orange, colorprimaryDark=Black.

check below code:

```
<!-- Light application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FD8300</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#F59F00</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <!-- v7.widget.CardView background color -->
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
    <item name="txtBgStyle">@style/CardView.Light</item>
</style>

<!-- Dark application theme. -->
<style name="DarkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FD8300</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B1C1C</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FAFAFA</item>
    <!-- v7.widget.CardView background color -->
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/cardStyle</item>
    <item name="txtBgStyle">@style/txtBgStyle</item>
</style>
<style>
```

[image: Please See the image for more clarity]

Comment: Hi, yes but <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B1C1C</item> in the light theme changes the statusbar to dark, it should stay orange when the light theme is applied. Statusbar should get black when the dark theme is applied. See my 2nd screenshot. Is it something in my manifest? No matter what I try the statusbar stays orange when applying the dark theme.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I apply the dark theme, statusbar stays orange and does not go black. I applied the light theme in my Android Manifest: <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> does that not have something to do with it? I have the feeling it does.

Comment: Ok, very simple, User applies dark theme, statusbar should also get black but stays orange (see my 2nd screenshot). User applies light theme, statusbar should change to orange (see my 1st screenhot). That`s all.
Both themes are set in my styles.xml file but the dark theme does not work. (statusbar stays orange but should change to black), <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B1C1C</item>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106694/discussion-between-narendra-baratam-and-simon).

Answer (score 0):

This is for those who is struggling to change color of status bar in light and dark mode.
Firstly, check if device is in dark mode options or not.
After that apply this method to change color of status bar. It worked fine in my device.

```
fun checkDarkMode(context: Context): Boolean {

    val nightModeFlags: Int =
        context.resources.configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
    when (nightModeFlags) {
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}




fun setStatusBarColor(activity: Activity){
   var isInDarkMode= checkDarkMode(activity)
    val window = activity.window
    if (isInDarkMode) {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.black)
    } else {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.white)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
    }
}
```