# My app status bar appears lighter than the app bar, even after setting the same color

Tags: android, android-theme, android-statusbar, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

Status bar of android app appears lighter than the app bar even after setting the same color.

My app has two themes for day and night (dark) mode. Interestingly the status bar and action bar / app bar looks completely homogeneous (same color) when app is viewed in light theme mode (Not Night Mode). But when viewed in Night Mode (Dark mode) the status bar looks lighter in color.

I have used exactly same color for colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark in both the themes and other theme setup is also same.(Please look at the image carefully as it is a shade of dark grey, it is difficult to differentiate between the status bar color and app bar color)

What can I do correct this. I want the same color to both status bar and app bar, as it is there in the light mode of the app.

I hope the question is understandable. Thanks!![image: dark mode status bar][image: light mode status bar]

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079983/dark-theme-not-applied-correctly-statusbar-color-unchanged solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, it is somewhere close to the solution. Thanks!